# c++ merge sort won't merge?

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, mergesort

Im trying to make this mergesort function to sort a vector or word nodes (contains word length, number of occurences, and the word itsself) It seems to enter the merge function once, then the program fails, any ideas?

```
bool Utility::mergeSort_occurences(vector<Word> &invector){
    if (invector.size() <= 1){
        return true;
    }
    vector<Word> left, right;
    int middle = (invector.size()/2);
    for(int i = 0 ; i < middle ; i++){
        left.push_back(invector[i]);
    }
    for(int i = middle ; i < invector.size() ; i++){
        right.push_back(invector[i]);
    }
    mergeSort_occurences(left);
    mergeSort_occurences(right);
    invector = mergeOccurences(left, right);
    return true;
}

vector<Word> Utility::mergeOccurences(vector<Word> &left, vector<Word> &right){
    vector<Word> mergelist;
    while(left.size() > 0 || right.size() > 0){
        if(left.size() > 0 && right.size() > 0){
            if(left[0].getOccurences() <= right[0].getOccurences()){
                mergelist.push_back(left[0]);
                left.erase(left.begin());
            }else{
                mergelist.push_back(right[0]);
                right.erase(right.erase(right.begin()));
            }
        }
        else if(left.size() > 0){
           mergelist.push_back(left[0]);
           left.erase(left.begin()); 
        }
        else if(right.size() > 0){
           mergelist.push_back(right[0]);
           right.erase(right.erase(right.begin()));            
        }
    }
    return mergelist;
}
```

Comment: Yes - you could debug it.  Run through the code with your debugger using a trivially small dataset in your vector.  Four values, say.  It should then be reasonably easy to find out where the problem lies, much easier than, say, trying to spot the problem by staring at a pageful of complex vector/array handling code written by someone else.

Answer (score 1):

Your `right.erase(right.erase(right.begin()));` code looks dodgy. The `erase` function returns an iterator to the successor of the element which was deleted, which is the `end()` if you deleted the last element.

You're guarding this code with  `right.size() > 0` which only guarantees there is one item. You have two erase operations.

Have you looked into the consequences of doing `erase` on `right.end()`?